# Don't get tweet with stream API in Node

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm working with [Twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) to get a nice wrapper around the Twitter API. I have a cron to get all the tweet on a particular hashtag. It increment the counter everytime there's a new tweet, and at the end of the period, save it in to the database (MongoDB). Only problem is, it always return me 0.
Here is the code

```
new cronJob('00 */5 * * * *', function(){ // start parsing 5mn after call, and every 5mn then
        var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'hashtag' })
        var counter = 0;
        var date = new Date();
        var collection = client.collection("TweetsNumber");

        stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
          console.log(tweet);
          counter += 1;
        })

        collection.insert({Date: date, CrawledTweets: counter, Channel: "someChannel"});
        console.log(counter + " tweets saved in DB");

    }, null, true, "Europe/Paris");
```

According to the doc, the "stream.on" method is called everytime there's a new tweets. I use some trending topic to be sure to have data, but it's like it is never called, and I really don't know why.
Hope you can help. Have a great day !

EDIT: T is already create in another part of the program, and with other functionnalities, it is working. Same for client, which is my db.

EDIT: Thanks to Shodan, it works now, see the [github issue](https://github.com/ttezel/twit/issues/42). Thanks a lot !

Comment: i cant find a problem in this code, can you try replacing the cron using `setInterval` to check if there are problems with the cronJob?

Comment: I know it's working, I got the last console.log every 5 minutes as I should.

Comment: yes i know that, i thought about keeping the execution context closer to the `T` object as i dont know much about the execution context of the cronJob

Comment: do other methods like post work this way? Or maybe the REST interface?

Comment: The REST API works, but I can't count the tweets from the last 5 minutes. It only returns the last (max) 100 tweets. So for stats, it isn't useful.

Comment: does it trigger the `stream.on('connect'` event?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25692/discussion-between-pfried-and-simon)

Comment: The code you have looks fine. Can you add the following code to see if the 'disconnect' and 'reconnect' events are firing?

    stream.on('disconnect', function (disconnectMessage) {
      console.log('disconnect', disconnectMessage)
    })

    stream.on('reconnect', function () {
      console.log('reconnecting')
    })

Comment: the reconnecting one fire, didn't see the disconnect. Reconnecting happens a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the tweets logged to your console?

If yes, then it is not a twit problem, since it exactly does what you told it to.

As I read your code correctly, you create a `cronjob`, which fires once every 5 minutes.

- It connects a new local stream, which should output to the console and increase the counter for the next 5 minutes.
- It insert into the global `client.collection("TweetNumbers")`, with the local variable counter having a value of 0
- it `console.log(counter + " tweets saved in DB");`, with the local variable counter having a value of 0
- The function then exits, and is fresh started in 5 minutes.
- stream.on should continue to fire when ever a tweet comes along for the next 5 minutes and increase the counter, BUT the counter is never used again by `collection.insert` and the second `console.log`.

This is because you restart the function creating new local variables for all the stuff and logging the initial values again.

Comment: No, the tweet are not logged, that's the problem.  
And that's not exactly what I'm trying to do.  
I want to increase the counter every time a tweet comes in and save this number after 5 minutes, and doing it again. I thouht you could declare the var then increase and it would be store, to us it off the stream, but maybe it doesn't work in Node because of the specificity of the langage, if so, a pointer on how to do that would be very much appreciated :D

Comment: I think the problem is that the local variable ```stream``` where you store the stream-object is destroyed when the function exits and thus in the next tick of the event loop there is no stream-object that can fire anything.
Check your issue on github, I have written some example code that should solve your problem. (Not tested, though.)

Answer (score 1):

You set `var counter = 0` and then immediately `console.log()` it, which means the 'tweet' event never gets a chance to fire and increase counter. You might want to do this:

new cronJob('00 */5 * * * *', function(){ // start parsing 5mn after call, and every 5mn then
        var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'hashtag' })
        var counter = 0;
        var date = new Date();
        var collection = client.collection("TweetsNumber");

```
    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
      console.log(tweet);

      collection.insert({Date: date, CrawledTweets: counter, Channel: "someChannel"});
      counter += 1;

      console.log(counter + " tweets saved in DB");
    })
}, null, true, "Europe/Paris");
```

Comment: I tried that code and I got neither of the console.log :/ I tried to put one before the stream event, and it comes fine, so it's like the event stream.on is not triggered.